# How to disable emoji I see sometimes while browsing?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, web-browsing, emoji

Some time ago I saw emoji in my Google Plus and thought, that it is another crappy update, but seems like is it Mac OS who place them instead of text.

[image]

How to turn them off?
Mac OS X 10.9.4

Or is it about Chrome 41.0?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling/hiding emojis in content is just like hiding any other type of content you do not wish to see. In this instance, you cannot use a content blocker but rather you will need to use a user script to find and remove/replace all characters in the agreed Emoji ranges.

I use Safari Extension [QuickScript](http://canisbos.com/quickscript#howtouse) with this script to remove all Emoji from the page after the page has finished loading:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])/g, '')
```

Testing on the following page results in no emoji being visible: http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/emoji-test.txt

Answer (score 0):

Some sites automatically replace text smilies with emoji-style characters.

Stack Exchange doesn't & the Mac doesn't by default [nor can I find any way to make it other than in specific apps like Skype & Messages], so a simple test may be to look at this with both Chrome & another browser & see if one replaces

:') [colon apostrophe close bracket]

with

[emoji, unicode U+1F602 ]

If so, that's where to look.
If not, then that's what character was placed there by either the site in question, or the user who posted that message.

Comment: So it must be users who put this unicode into their messages (whether they want it or not) -- does it mean it is unlikely solvable? I doubt someone implement the unicode_emoji->ascii converter inside Mac OS or Chromium.

Comment: If either a user has input emoji, or that site has auto-translated it to emoji - like with Messages,  then it is forever now emoji & can't really be auto-translated back. If, on the other hand, it was done client-side it could be turned off - like with Skype. From a single picture from a single site on a single browser it's impossible to tell which it is.